# How to repeatedly execute nodejs mysql query until desire result come out?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, node-mysql

```
conn.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var prizeCode = generatePrizeCode();// this method return a 5-digit code
        var query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE code = ? ";
        var values = [[prizeCode]];
        conn.query(query, [values], function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            // Here I want to re-execute the above query if the result is not empty 
        });
    });
```

In the above code, I want to execute query as long as the result contain data. But I cannot use the loop like following pseucode,

```
// if the result is empty, the generated code does not exist in database. So it can be used.
while(result.length != 0){
    var result = conn.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE code = abc");
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What would you like to achieve?

You want to retry if any is coming or you want to run the same code to an indefinite number?

Comment: @AnoopMc I want to repeatedly execute the query as long as the query result contain data (one or more rows).

Comment: You could create a method that will keep trying until the result is there. So basically ti will call the method again if there is any error. To avoid infinite loop you could use the maximum number of retries with a counter.

Comment: @AnoopMc Will you please elaborate or give an example link?

Comment: Sure, have added the code snippet in the answers. Please modify and use.

Comment: If I understand, correctly ‘setInterval’ is your friend

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use callbacks or promises/async functions. Here's how it could be written with callbacks:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const retryLimit = 50;

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  database: 'test',
  host: 'localhost',
  password: 'hunter2',
  user: 'dave',
});

function getData(attempts, cb) {
  if (attempts < retryLimit) { // we haven't exausted our attempts yet
    const code = generatePrizeCode();
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE code = ?', code, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return cb(err);
      }
      if (result.length > 0) { // code already exists
        getData(attempts + 1, cb); // recurse
      } else { // this is a new code
        cb(null, code); // return the new code via the callback function
      }
    });
  } else { // we have exausted our attempts
    return cb(new Error('retry limit exceeded'));
  }
}

getData(0, (err, code) => {
  // do what you want here, e.g., console.log(code)
  connection.end();
});
```

Note that this can cause node to crash if you recurse too many times and exceed the maximum call stack. One way around that is to call setImmediate or setTimeout instead of recursing directly. Instead of the line

```
getData(attempts + 1, cb); // recurse
```

use

```
setImmediate(() => {
  getData(attempts + 1, cb); // recurse
});
```

or

```
// recurse, using setImmediate every 1000th time
if (attempts % 1000 === 0) {
  setImmediate(() => {
    getData(attempts + 1, cb); // recurse
  });
} else {
  getData(attempts + 1, cb); // recurse
}
```

Using promises and async/await style would clean this up a lot and probably look more like what you're used to (note this uses the `promise-mysql` library):

```
const mysql = require('promise-mysql');

async function getData(connection) {
  const retryLimit = 50;
  for (let i = 0; i < retryLimit; i++) {
    const code = generatePrizeCode();
    const result = await connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE code = ?', code);
    if (result.length === 0) { // this code doesn't exist yet
      return code;
    }
  }
  throw new Error('retry limit exceeded');
}

(async () => {
  try {
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
      database: 'test',
      host: 'localhost',
      password: 'hunter2',
      user: 'dave',
    });
    try {
      const code = await getData(connection);
      // do what you want here, e.g., console.log(code)
    } finally {
      connection.end();
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

basically you gonna need to work with async\await or promises(pretty much the same).
 https://javascript.info/async-await
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

this way your gonna be able to only return when you get the right result for you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  host     : 'YOUR_HOST_NAME',
  user     : 'YOUR_USER_NAME',
  password : 'YOUR_PASSWORD',
  database : 'YOUR_DATABASE'
});

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  // connected! (unless `err` is set)
});


connection = mysql.createPool
var retryLimit=0;

var getData = function () {
if(retryLimit <= 50)
{
retryLimit++;
connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE code = abc', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) {throw error;}
  else if(result.length <1) {
getData();
//call the same method again.
}
});
}
}


getData();
```

You could add else statements and do whatever you want.

Comment: What if there's a large no. of users in database whose codes are present? In that case, the call stack will grow quite large and the code might crash with a Maximum Call Stack size exceeded exception.

Comment: Don’t do this. Indeed max. callstack is going to be an issue here.